# All titlebars are missing If always show menus is activated

Tags: unity, 14.10, titlebar

I used the command : 
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true

on Ubuntu 14.04 to activate always show menu option and it worked but the only annoying bug is all title bars are missing and I had to deactivate this option to restore title bars. I noticed that title bars occupies the same place of menus . I wonder if there is a solution for my problem.